# Calculate how much smaller a square would have to be to fit after rotated 45 degrees

Tags: math, rotation

Background: I'm creating a UI element in Unity and need to rotate it. It's a square, and will be rotated 45 degrees. Since rotation in Unity's UI happens *after* all sizing and positioning is done, the corners of this square stick outside the maximum area.

So I have a square inside a square. By default it's the same size as the parent square. After rotating 45 degrees, it's too large to fit in the parent square. How do I calculate the percentage by which to scale down the child square *before* rotating to make it fit inside the parent square *after* rotating?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I don't find that to be helpful at all, sorry. Specifically, knowing what Pythagorean theorem is doesn't help me know how to apply that theory to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A square of edge length `a` has a diagonal of length `d = sqrt(2)*a`, because, by Pythagoras theorem, the triangle formed by the diagonal and two of the square's edges satisfies `d^2 = a^2 + a^2 = 2*a^2`.

Therefore the inner square must be scaled by `1/sqrt(2)` which is identical to `sin(pi/4) = sin(45°)` and `cos(pi/4) = cos(45°)` and approximately `0.7071...`.

If the scaling is performed centered at the sqaure's center, it doesn't matter whether rotation happens before or after scaling.

Comment: The reason I mention that rotation happens after scaling is because that means I can't just specify the parent square's size and have it fit. But yes, the rotation does happen around the centre. Also, are you sure `sin(pi/4)` is correct? I don't get a correct answer when I try that. Luckily I realised by chance that `sin(45)` is correct, so I can also know that `sin(pi/4)` appears to be incorrect :P But if I'm misunderstanding, feel free to explain further.

Comment: I never would have realised the connection to Pythagoras theorem, btw. That's the sort of thing that's not intuitive unless you already know it :P So I appreciate your explanation.

Comment: @Clonkex `sin(pi/4)` is correct, but `pi/4 = 45°`. Usually the trigonometric functions expect the argument value in radians (`pi/4`), but sometimes, especially on calculators, they may expect the argument value in degrees (`45`). In programming languages this is usually not the case.

Comment: Ah I see, I was definitely working in degrees. I see if I switch my calculator to radians I get the correct answer. It also makes intuitive sense: if a full circle is 2pi radians, pi would be half a circle and pi/4 would be an 8th of a circle, or 45°. Good answer, you get an upvote and shiny green tick! :) Also if you're wondering, trig is one of my weaker areas. I never really did trig in school so it's always a bit of a struggle for me.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I just figured it out. The size of the child square needs to be a percentage of the parent square's size, which we can get from the sine (or cosine also works, I think?) of 45 degrees.

`sin(45) == 0.70710678118654752440084436210485`

To get to that size, I need to reduce my child square's size by the difference between 100% and 70.7106...%.

`1 - sin(45) == 0.29289321881345247559915563789515`

Since I'm using Unity and controlling the size of my square UI element with anchor positions, I just divided that by 2 and set the min X anchor to 0.146 and the max X anchor to 0.854. With an Aspect Ratio Fitter component set to `Width Controls Height` and a ratio of 1, this causes my child square to always fit perfectly inside my parent square even when rotated.